# ¿Qué aparatos tecnológicos usas?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

¿Qué aparatos tecnológicos  usas? This is a question I must answer for my work. I am only a secondary student, so low vocabulary is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically asking us to do someone's homework for them, without showing any previous effort on their part.  There's also no indication of what is confusing about the homework question.  Is it vocabulary?  Grammar?

Comment: Hola Jye. Bienvenido. Mira la [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour) para enterarte como funciona el sitio y cuáles respuestas son ideales. Esta pregunta necesita desarrollarse más. Cuando la hayas mejorado la desbloquearé. ¡Que te diviertas! Recuerda que no estamos para hacer tus tareas. Preguntas específicas si respondemos.

Answer (score 1):

It means that: what technology devices do you use?

It would be interesting that you provide the answer you would give in English, so we can help you to say that in Spanish.

E.g:

Normalmente uso el ordenador para diferentes actividades, como por ejemplo, navegar por Internet o hacer presentaciones Power Point. También, uso mucho el teléfono móvil, ya que me permite estar en contacto con mis conocidos. Además, con el teléfono móvil puedo hacer fotos y compartirlas en las redes sociales.

In English:

I usually use the computer for different activities, for instance, to surf the Internet or to make Power Point presentations. I also use a lot the cell phone, since it helps me stay in touch with my acquaintances. I can also use the cell phone to take pictures and share them on social networks.